# !+x operator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, symbols

my first question here! Apologies if a duplicate - couldn't find an answer.

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, currently doing some exercises and I've just ran across a line I can't grasp the meaning of. Here it is:

`!+x && x !== '0'`

What does `!+x` perform here? Line's an excerpt from a script that validates IP adresses.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unary `+` makes it a number if possible, `!` negates its truthy or falsy value. Basically it’s an attempt to check if `x` is a number.

Comment: Thank you Sami Kuhmonen! Simple and to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks if the `x` variable, when converted into a number, is falsey (0 or NaN), and isn't the literal string `'0'`.

Eg `'0.00'` will fulfill the conditions, as will `'foo'`, but `'0'` won't.

The `+` is unary +, converting the expression that follows into a number. Then the `!` negates the boolean value of that number.